# Call settings will pop-up when I open a pdf

Tags: pdf

So dear clever IT friends here is the thing. I am helping a nice old grandma. She has a Huawei tablet, android in it. The silly device asked when she opened a pdf file "which program would you like to use to open it". She is a nice 80 years old granny and thought she has to go with settings. So she went for it. Now when you try open any pdf file the "call settings will" pop-up instead the pdf file itself. 
Any idea how I can find the path to add adobe to pdf files?

Answer (score 0):

**Easier solution:**

Hi, the easiest solution is to uninstall and re-install the PDF viewer app from that tablet. Android starts prompting how to open that file as soon as it notices that there are new apps which can handle that file type.

Since you mentioned Adobe Reader, please uninstall it and then install it again from the Play Store. The prompt to select which app to open the PDF with will return. There you can set Adobe as the default to avoid problems in the future.

**Appropriate solution:**

I am keeping this as a second choice because the Android version is unknown and different OEMs can have a slightly different settings page and slightly different names for each setting item. Still, here we go:

1. Open Settings app.
2. Open *Apps and Notifications* (Or Apps, or something similar which conveys the same meaning).
3. Tap on *All Apps* (Can also be *See all apps* or not exist at all, just choose the option which takes you to the full list of apps)
4. Scroll down and locate the *Settings* app. Tap on it.
5. Scroll and select *Advanced > Open by Default*.
6. Finally tap on the *Clear all defaults* button.

This will remove the default handler for PDF files and Android should once again start offering the choice.